# Unable to find conky file

Tags: conky

I installed conky but can not find the conky file. I also turned on "show hidden" but it is not showing. I rebooted my PC and checked that I have installed conky. It was installed but the file was missing.

Comment: When you say the conky file, you mean the conky config directory? Try looking for a .conky folder in the $HOME folder, if not, maybe check in the .config folder, or try reinstalling conky.

Comment: It should be ~/.conkyrc and if it's not there you may need to create it. Examples should exist in `/etc/conky/conky.conf`.

Comment: Try this: `find $HOME -iname .conkyrc` , this should find your config file in your home directory...